# Is there a way to activate wordpress theme without going to admin panel

Tags: wordpress

If I am having a theme installed in my project.So, I have downloaded a theme and unzipped it in wp-contents theme directory.

Now as we all know we can activate it by going to appearance->theme->and then chose the theme and click activate.

I am wondering if there is a way I can activate the theme without going to admin panel.

Guessing a way for to change the theme from somewhere in my database or something like that.

So, if there is a way, I would love to know.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-theme-in-db

Comment: helpful link.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. You can change it hard way in database.

Go to database, table **wp_options** and find line with `template` and `stylesheet` option (around line 41,42)

If you change there option on exact name of folder where is your template stored, it should change it as current.

If you have problems with loading template, there is one more line to watch over named: `_site_transient_theme_roots`, here is something like path to template stored.